# Windows Form not changing underlying Entity Data

Tags: winforms, forms, entity-framework, datagridview, updating

Can anyone see the simple mistake that I can't?

I am opening a form to allow assigning Job Numbers to invoices that do not have any.

This is the code in the applications main form that handles this:

```
Dim unknownJobs = From pur In context.Purchases
                  Where pur.SentToMyob = False AndAlso
                        pur.Job.JobNumber = String.Empty
                  Select pur

If unknownJobs.Any Then
    frmJobs2.JobsBindingSource.DataSource = (From j In context.Jobs1
                                            Order By j.JobNumber
                                            Select j).ToList
    frmJobs2.PurchasesBindingSource.DataSource = unknownJobs
    Progress.Hide()
    If frmJobs2.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        context.SaveChanges()
    End If
End If
```

This is the Form that gets opened with the relevant column details displayed

[image]

The Code behind is simple and consists of:

```
Public Class FormJobs2
    ''' <summary>
    ''' OK clicked
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub OKButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OKButton.Click
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Cancel clicked
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub SkipButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SkipButton.Click
        Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

What happens when it runs is that you can select the job numbers BUT they do not display on the DataGridView and do not update the underlying context.

Where is the stupid mistake, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if you are trying to assign your `frmJobs2.PurchasesBindingSource.DataSource` an IQueryable.

The line should read:

```
frmJobs2.PurchasesBindingSource.DataSource = unknownJobs.ToList
```